Why is Flutter Android emulator screen only visible in the task bar, doesn't appear on the screen
[enter image description here][1]I tried to build Flutter applications using my Android emulator setup from the Android command-line tools. However, when I try to run it, the emulator only shows up like this: Emulator stuck in taskbar on Windows 11. I have created multiple virtual devices, but all of them have the same issue. Sadly, the emulator only shows in the taskbar, and when I click on it, it doesn't appear on the screen. When I click on qemu-system-x86_64.exe, an error is shown. Even when I double-click on the screen, nothing happens. By the way, I’m using ** Windows 11**, and my CPU is a Ryzen 5000 series. I turned on hyper-v but However, this issue hasn't been resolved by any of the solutions I found. hope someon help me fix this[tag:flutter
like this :
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/TpSrxr4J.png

Are you using Android Studio? Regardless of which IDE, can you please show how you create an emulator? Then, if there's a complete logs about the exception you've encountered, kindly show it as well.

It could get a higher chance to be answered correctly.


Maximize Window: Right-click the emulator in the taskbar and select "Maximize."
Change Graphics Mode: Use Software graphics in AVD settings.
Restart Emulator: Close and restart it from the AVD Manager.
Update Emulator: Update via Android Studio’s SDK Manager.
Recreate Emulator: Delete and create a new one in AVD Manager.
Update Graphics Drivers: Ensure GPU drivers are up to date.
Enable Virtualization: Enable in BIOS (Intel HAXM/AMD Hypervisor).
Check Monitors: Drag the window to another screen if using multiple monitors.


If the emulator doesn’t appear on the screen, try changing the screen resolution. This trick has worked for me on a MacBook. Once the emulator appears, switch back to the normal resolution

What is the error that you are receiving?
For me, the first option below usually works well.
You can try:

Tools - Device Manager.
In the Actions column, click in three dots on
the right and then Wipe Data.

or

Search for *.lock folders under .android folder and delete those. This
should tell Android studio that the AVD is not running.

or

Remove all *.lock files in the avd folder
Go to File->Invalidates cache then click "Just restart"
Open Android Studio again and launching the emulator should work as it
is not lock anymore after deleting the .lock files.

